# Flash Player Cache problem

Tags: flash

I made a flash video jukebox, so it reads a dynamic playlist of F4V files for hours.
Everything works well but after about 45 min the sound stops and after 2 hours the flash player plug in crashes.
It seems like the cache is not accepting more F4V videos and then crashes. If I auto-refresh the browser every 2 hours it works but I would like to avoid having to refresh the browser and just clear the flash player cache if that's where the F4V go?
I can't find any info about where the F4V files go when you play them!

### Edit

Frame 1 gives the variable `vidReference` the value of the video file name:

`VidReference = trackToPlay;`

Frame 2 does the playing:

`var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

    nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

const buffer_time:Number = 2;

ns.bufferTime = buffer_time;

ns.client = this;

ns.play(VidReference);

var vid:Video = new Video();

vid.attachNetStream(ns);

addChild(vid);

vid_frame.addChild(vid);`

This is the function that detects when video is done playing, still on frame 2:

`function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void

{

  switch (event.info.code)

{

 case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound": newTrack();

break;

case "NetStream.Play.Stop": newTrack();

break;

}

}`

And the function `newTrack()` is just giving the variable `trackToPlay` a value (the file name of the next video). And then says to `gotoAndPlay` frame 1, so it kind of reinitializing the player. The objects are re declared in frame 2, is that the problem here?

David

Answer (score 1):

sounds like it's running out of memory. are you clearing out the old f4v's so that you're never just continuously requesting memory?

try profiling it, or use something like http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/

for help tracking memory problems, check out http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3 (shameless self promotion)

Comment: I actually was hoping that it was possible to clear the old F4V, is that possible? They definitaly take all the memory after a while and I'm pretty sure that's why it crashes.
How do I clear old F4V once played?

Comment: you need to make sure there's nothing holding links to it - in the player, lists, whatever. depending on your setup, you may need to restructure a bit. basically, i'd hold maybe the name of the file, plus a small image so people know what it is. i'd only have one video file at a time in the SWF

Answer (score 0):

Its not a cache issue. Cache is allocated space on your hard drive  so if that is not full you will not have an issue.
It sounds move like you are not garbage collecting and not reusing the video object properly.
Post some code so we can fix it

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your code in there. Much easier for me to break it down for you

Comment: Frame 1 gives the variable vidReference the value of the video file name: `VidReference = trackToPlay;`

Frame 2 does the playing: 
`var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler); nc.connect(null); 
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler); 
const buffer_time:Number = 2; 
ns.bufferTime = buffer_time; 
ns.client = this; 
ns.play(VidReference); 
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns); 
addChild(vid); 
vid_frame.addChild(vid);`

Comment: This is the function that detects when video is done playing, still on frame 2:`function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void { switch (event.info.code) { case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound": newTrack(); break; case "NetStream.Play.Stop": newTrack(); break; } }` And the function newTrack is just giving the variable trackToPlay a value (the file name of the next video). And then says to gotoAndPlay frame 1, so it kind of reinitialise the player. The objects are re declared in frame 2, is that the problem here?

Comment: Please post this code in your original question. Its a pain to read it like this. Also include your newTrack( ); function.